# First page of SSRS report not rendering on initial load

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, reportbuilder3.0

I've created an SSRS report in Report Builder 3 which contains a single-rowed Tablix that holds a sub report which produces a single report per page. The problem is that when I run the report it doesn't render the first page.

Within Report Builder I can never get this first page to display within the executed report and within the web forms ReportViewer control (v10.0.0.0) I can get this first page to appear when I page away and then back to it. Exporting the report also displays all of the correct data.

This issue has only started occurring since I made some slight changes to the layout of the sub report. I've checked the visibility on the tablix, group, row, sub report and all the other settings that I thought might be responsible, but they haven't changed since it was previously working.

I've also tried recreating both the tablix and the entire outer report based on an answer to a similar question and this didn't make a difference.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was passing the data for my sub reports through as parameters to prevent the need to call 5000+ single line select statements, and it looks like they need a data set to execute to render correctly on the initial load. Previously, I had mistakenly left a data set within the report, which I must have removed when making the layout changes.

Creating a dummy data set with `SELECT ' ' AS Dummy` and then using that to populate a text box seemingly fixed the issue. It's not a clean solution but it works.

Comment: Unbelievable, but it works.